# How do integrate FaceBook/Twitter button's into my iOS app game

Tags: ios, facebook, twitter, share, share-button

I'm not asking how to create a button, i'm asking how to integrate FaceBook and Twitter into my iOS game. I see games that let you click on a FaceBook button and a Twitter button. When you click on Twitter button there's a custom message of your score and a SHARE button to post your results on Twitter.

How do I do this? Mr. Jump game does this. I want to do the same. My app is for iOS 7 and iOS 8

So what i'd like to happen is when the user reaches a score of 10 for example. When user clicks on the Twitter button a custom message pops up like "you've got 10 points" or something and then a SHARE button to post this on the user's twitter page. This is what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way you could accomplish this is using the [Social Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Social/Reference/Social_Framework/index.html) with SLComposeServiceViewController. It has been available since iOS 6.

```
if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter])
{
    SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [SLComposeViewController 
        composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
    [tweetSheet setInitialText:@"I got 10 points!"];
    [self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: That's not what I was looking for. I'm not looking for the user to type a tweet. I'm looking for when user clicks the Twitter button a pop up appears and in the pop up it states the high score the user reached and then there's a SHARE button that when clicked, that message appears on twitter.

Comment: @Jet this is the correct answer for what you were asking from the documentation: `On iOS only, the Social framework provides a generalized interface for posting requests on behalf of the user.` using from the example above, you would use `[tweetSheet setInitialText:@"you've got 10 points"];` to set up the custom tweet of "you've got 10 points" with the Share button available for the user to post on the twitter feed.  They would not have to type this themselves, as the text is already provided via the `setInitialText:` method.

Comment: That's the thing.  I'd want the custom message to be based on what the user scored and not what I typed in for the user to see in setInitialText method.